# Remove contents from a string comma and bracket

Tags: php, trim

I want to filter a string with my requirements

```
$string="my super city (name , result)";
```

I want only `result` as output.

Any experts ???

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the criterion? last word between parentheses?

Comment: last word after comma in the bracket..that is `result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform a replacement:

```
$result = preg_replace( '/.*?,\s*(\w+)\).*?/', '\1', $string );
```

In `$result` you have this:

```
result
```

If you want match **every** not-comma characters, use this regular expression instead:

```
/.*?,\s*([^,]+)\).*?/
```

1st pattern explaination:

```
/
.*?     zero-or-more characters
,       a comma
\s*     zero-or-more spaces
(\w+)   Group 1: one-or-more word characters
\)      closing bracket
.*?     zero-or-more characters
/
```

<kbd>**[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/sE2wY0/1)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. Take a look at explaination: maybe some part can be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$full = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z ]/", '', $string);
```

if you need numerics(0-9) also, then try

```
$full = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", '', $string);
```

**EDIT:**

Then

```
 $exp = explode(" ", $full);
 echo $exp[count($exp)-1];
```

Comment: You fast replier..This display all , i need last word after comma in bracket... is this possible???

Comment: what is $split used for sir? beacuse it still same result